# I want to disable the access of a directory but not the child directory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I want to disable the access of a directory but not the child directory with .htaccess

i already written a rewrite rules to redirect everything to a child directory (public_html), but its parent is still accessible if the user know the url, i want to disable the access of the current directory not the child directory

```
    # Turn on rewrites.
    RewriteEngine on

    # Only apply to URLs on this domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$

    # Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/

    # Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite all those to insert /folder.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1

    # Also redirect the root folder.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use two .htaccess file, or two Directory section in your main server config (the first solution is easier if your server permits .htaccess files).

Put in your root a .htaccess with content like this:

```
Allow from none
Deny from all
```

And put one in your `public_html` folder with content:

```
Allow from all
```

This way nothing will be accessible in your root, but your `public_html` overrides this, and in that, everything will be accessible.

#### Edit:

What you want can be accomplished by putting this .htacces in your root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/$1
```

and putting your original one in `public_html` and make modifications to that to reflect that it is now in the `public_html` folder. This configuration that I posted is responsible to skip the root directory, and pretend like the `public_html` would be the root.

Comment: my original redirect code cannot work anymore, i have to type in www.domain.com/public_html/

Comment: Could you show me your original .htacecss? Because I think, if you do not give conditions for your first RewriteRule in your root, then nothing in it will be accessible. The only downside of this is that /public_html/something URLs will still work, and you have to use your conditional rewrites in your public_html's .htaccess with `RewriteBase /` preceding them. That's what I use for MVC frameworks.

Comment: can i use anything to just hide away the public_html directory path from the url?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a solution where you can keep your old htaccess configuration, and completely redirect to the `public_html` folder.